# CakePHP: Unsure how to handle a semi difficult relationship

Tags: database, cakephp, relationship

I'm working on my first CakePHP app, an order/invoice system. The order-part are coming along nicely, but for the invoices I kinda need some help.

The [database structure](http://uploads.navale.nl/vsa22-database.pdf) I'm using; A **delivery note** consists of multiple **products**, which in turn exist of multiple re-usable **elements** (like a number of trays and the product itself). Now because some customer order larger quantities, they get lower rates, which are time-based (from week 1 to 9 €1 for element y, and from week 10 to 8 €1.20 for the same element). Of course some customers just have to use the daily prices, which will be stored the same way, just witha `nulled` customer_id.

Now my problem; I have absolutely no idea how I should tackle the invoice view, or more specifically; what the best way is to get the data, or if I should just go and practice my SQL-writing skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing any major problems with your schema.  The Containable behavior should make things easy here.  Add it to your Invoice model:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Make your life easier by adding a **DefaultPrice** relationship for each element.  In your Element model:

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'DefaultPrice' => array(
        'className' => 'Price',
        'foreignKey' => 'element_id',
        'conditions' => array('DefaultPrice.customer_id IS NULL')
    )
);
```

Now to build your invoice, set up and pass a contain parameter to your find operation. (I assume you want to show a breakdown of element costs, right?)

```
$contain  = array(
    'DeliveryNote' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'Element' => array(
                 'DefaultPrice',
                 'Price' => array(
                     'conditions' => array('Price.customer_id' => $customer_id)
                 )
             )
         )
     )
);
$this->Invoice->find('first', array('conditions' => ..., 'contain' => $contain));
```

This should result in each Element record including a DefaultPrice, and if the customer is receiving special pricing, the Price record will also be included.

**Note:** You may want to consider including a **default_price** field in the Element field, and avoid having to do the additional join above.  Every Element is going to have a default price, right?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that some element-pricing needs to be date based. It's for a strawberry-processing firm, and the prices fluctuate based on demand and season.

Comment: You achieve that by passing additional conditions for Price in the contain parameter where you're passing the $customer_id.  ie: 'Price.from' <= $now   / 'Price.to' >= $now.  If Price ends up being empty, you should default to the DefaultPrice.

Comment: Hmm, but since I'll have to use the DeliveryNote.delivery_date, I guess I first have to get all the DeliveryNotes for an Invoice, and then loop through the notes to get all elements. Right?

Comment: Does passing 'DeliveryNote.delivery_date' in the conditions work?  'Price.from' <= 'DeliveryNote.delivery_date'

Comment: Wow, didn't see that one coming! (though I still feel like a manual query would mean less wear on the database; this is easier to maintain)

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, it _doesn't_ work, for some reason my price query is looking like this:


SELECT `Price`.`id`, `Price`.`element_id`, `Price`.`customer_id`, `Price`.`from`, `Price`.`until`, `Price`.`price` FROM `prices` AS `Price` WHERE ((`Price`.`until` IS NULL) OR (`Price`.`until` >= 'DeliveryNote.delivery_date')) AND `Price`.`from` <= 'DeliveryNote.delivery_date' AND `Price`.`element_id` = (1) ORDER BY `Price`.`customer_id` desc LIMIT 1